Show that $PH\subseteq EXP$
The question is "Show that $PH\subseteq EXP$. In other words, show that any language $L\in PH$ can be decided in time $2^{O(n^c)}$ for some constant $c$. The PH here is referring to polynomial hierarchy. I only have some ideas on how to prove $NP\subseteq EXP$ by iterating through $2^{p(x)}$ certificates if the verifier for the NP language takes poly-time $p(x)$ to verify a certificate. However, I don't know how I should prove those problems that are not in $NP\cup coNP$ but in PH.

$k$ nested loops through polynomial-sized certificates takes exp(poly)exp(poly)...*exp(poly) (k factors) time, which is exp(poly).

$\mathbf{PH}$" />
According to $\mathbf{PH}$ definition, we just need polynomial space, say, $i\cdot q(n)$ to save $i$ certificates $u_1,\ldots,u_i$ and polynomial time, so polynomial space, to check $M(x,u_1,\ldots,u_i),$ if $L\in\Sigma_i^p$. Consequently, $\mathbf{PH}\subseteq\mathbf{PSPACE}\subseteq\mathbf{EXP}.$

Where is this definition sourced from?

It's from Arora and Barak's Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach
